# Why does strace return so many execve calls with ENOENT return code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wanted to use strace to see what was happening when I do `hadoop fs -ls ', so I ran the command:

`strace -f -e trace=execve hadoop fs -ls /stg` which resulted in a lot of output like this:

```
[pid 187050] execve("/opt/sas/app/platform/lsf/8.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/opt/sas/app/platform/lsf/8.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/opt/dca/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/usr/local/greenplum-cc-web/./bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/usr/local/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 187050] execve("/usr/bin/setsid", ["setsid", "bash", "-c", "echo $$"], [/* 78 vars */]) = 0
```

Why would there be so many `-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)` results?

Answer (score 9):

It's trying to run the program by calling every potential location in `$PATH`-order without foreknowledge of where the program is. This is completely normal because doing something like `stat()` then `execve()` is considered a race condition by security best practices in a lot of software shops.

Comment: The libc functions `execlp()` and `execvp()` implement this `PATH` searching. The type of race condition is known as "TOCTOU", time-of-check time-of-use: [CWE-367](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html)

Comment: Also, there is no point in doing checks first. You would just generate one extra system call.

Comment: If I recall correctly, execlp and execvp both call a shell to do the path search for you (in the same way).

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek None of the `exec` functions call a shell. They are all C library functions wrapping around the `execve` system call. The `execve` library call is a very thin wrapper, the other five `exec` functions need more logic and are likely implemented on top of the `execve` library call. The `system` library function does however call a shell.

Comment: [IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/exec.html) "In the cases where the other members of the exec family of functions would fail and set errno to [ENOEXEC], the execlp() and execvp() functions shall execute a command interpreter and the environment of the executed command shall be as if the process invoked the sh utility using execl() as follows [..]" Spec suggests otherwise...